# Eclipse keeps terminating my project when unauthorized to

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, netbeans-8

Whenever I run/debug any of my projects I don't get a window anymore and after about 20 seconds eclipse terminates it. I've tried re-installing Eclipse IDE. I only see console Outputs in when I use System.out.println();

I've tried Exporting it to Netbeans IDE it launches normally with this exception:

```
`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 480000
    at com.Mafia.graphics.Render3D.renderWall(Render3D.java:150)
at com.Mafia.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:33)
at com.Mafia.Display.render(Display.java:153)
at com.Mafia.Display.run(Display.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

But it the console in eclipse says nothing about any errors in Run Mode. I just found this in my debug console when debug "Mafia"(one of my projects)

```
<terminated, exit value: -1073740940>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe (2014-04-22 9:48:56 PM)
```

What does exit value mean and could it be linked to the problem?

I'm running:

Windows 7 sp1

JDK 1.7.0_55 (64-BIT)

JRE 7 (64-BIT)

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line?

Comment: No, but how would you run it from the command line?

Comment: Surely there's an exception and a stack trace in the console window?  If not, then Eclipse isn't terminating it, your program is terminating normally so there's a logic error in your code.

Comment: @Martymoose java MyMainClass

Comment: You need to execute `Java com.Mafia.Display` in you `\bin` directory because it is in a package.

Comment: @John It ran in the Command Line successfully.

Comment: @Jim Garrison does the Error Log count as a logic Error? I have 4 warnings in the Error Log.

Comment: @John What now? It only runs from the Command Line but not from the Run/Debug button in Eclipse.

Comment: @John added new information to the question

Comment: -1073740940 = 0xc0000374 = STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION.  According to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664497/cant-catch-0xc0000374-exception-status-heap-corruption it's not possible to use standard SEH to recover from this condition so RAS facilities in the JVM may not be triggered properly on its occurrence.

Comment: @Jim Garrison You were right all along is was this line that was the problem: render.renderWall(0, 1, 1, 0); But it needed to be like this: render.renderWall(0, 1, 2, 0); this was causing the crash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRASH WAS CAUSED BY ONE LINE I OVERLOOKED (Epic Fail on my part) was this line that was the problem: render.renderWall(0, 1, 1, 0); But it needed to be like this: render.renderWall(0, 1, 2, 0); this was causing the crash!

How I found out: Re-looked over my last written code!